# Microeconomics and management science of professional open source companies?

Tags: microeconomics, industrial-organisation, firm, theory-of-the-firm

Are there research (and stories more broadly) about professional open source companies? To what types of products their are appropriate, what licensing schemes to choose? How to managed patents and IP? How to motivate and build HR and how to attract volunteer community? How to involve academia in the project? How to organise ownership and how to achieve profitability? What is the past performance of the professional open source companies - what success stories and what failures, what are lessons learned?

This question seems to be quite broad, but the subject is nascent and therefore narrow. That is why this question is focused and narrow as well.

Comment: Does [this](https://techcrunch.com/2014/02/13/please-dont-tell-me-you-want-to-be-the-next-red-hat/) help? RedHat is the largest open-source company.